# takeown.exe: Succeeds in PHP sript, fails in cmd

Tags: windows, permissions, ownership

I created a cron job on my computer which runs a batch file as `LowCronUser`. Next, the batch runs a PHP script with the sole purpose of taking the ownership of a few files.
`LowCronUser` has basic rights, it is not part of any group, it has the `Take ownership of files or other objects` and `Allow log on locally` rights.

The PHP script works. Running `whoami` and `takeown` from this script returns the right user and success.  At the same time trying to get the ownership of the same files from a cmd instance(started with `runas`) running as `LowCronUser` it fails with: `The current logged on user does not have ownership privileges on the file`.

Could there be a difference between the cmd instance and the one task scheduler opens?

**Observations**

1. When trying to get the same ownership from the current running user(the one which I use to logon to the computer) `takeown` works.
2. `LowCronUser` has `Logon as batch user` right
3. I tried a simpler test: from task scheduler I run a batch script which tries to take ownership of some file. This works but fails from command prompt.
4. If I give `Full Control` to `LowCronUser` then it works(this is I believe because `Take Ownership` permission is also enabled)

**All rights assigned to cron-user:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: You've made a fair number of changes to these policies. In particular you granted your LowCronUser system-wide permission to take ownership of *any file object anywhere*, including objects to which that user does not have permission. You should revert your changes back to the defaults and see if your problem persists (and probably not put all of them back afterward).

Comment: You're telling me to remove the one permissions that I desperately need. I know what that right does, this is exactly what my problem is: it's not working from cmd ! How could the problem persist after I remove that right when my real problem is the fact that I can't take system-wide ownership?

Comment: No, I'm not telling you that permission is your problem, but rather that 1) changing any of these from their defaults invites trouble that you need to rule out by setting them back to the defaults then trying to repro the problem, and 2) The ownership right is system-wide. If that's ok with you--fine.

Comment: I wonder if the Take Ownership right is being filtered because you're not able to start the Command Prompt with elevated privileges...

Comment: No ideea. I abandoned the ideea. I never liked the right I was forced to give. My solutionis now to use permissions and grant Take Ownership